# Buttons in UI won't work until after page refresh in internet browsers

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, head

Buttons in my UI no longer work until after page refresh since adding the "font-awesome" CSS link in the head element of my main .jsp file.

Before my change (buttons worked):

```
<head>
<title>Foo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link href="web/ui/lib/bootstrap/v3_2_0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="web/ui/css/cloudoe_iframe.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After my change (buttons no longer work until refresh):

```
<head>
<title>Foo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link href="web/ui/lib/bootstrap/v3_2_0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="web/ui/css/cloudoe_iframe.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="web/ui/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I don't know that much about head elements and linking to CSS files, but clearly linking to the font-awesome CSS file is what broke it. By the way, Font Awesome is an open source icon library that I am using.

Example of a button:

```
<button style='float:right; margin-right: 20px;' class='darkBlueBorderButton' id='DownloadSDKsLink' href='#'>Download SDKs</button>
```

and the CSS:

```
.darkBlueBorderButton{
background-color: transparent;
height: 30px;
color: #152935;
border: 3px solid #152935;
width: 140px;
```

}

Comment: post the code for the buttons

Comment: what do you mean by "after page refresh"?

Comment: may just be a caching issue. try ctrl+shift+r

Comment: There are a plethora of buttons, but they're only basic HTML/CSS buttons linking to external sites. And my "after page refresh" I mean that the links to the buttons won't work until after you refresh the browser page. Then Whabam, magic happens and it works.

Comment: I also have this in my head element, but didn't paste because I thought it was irrelevant. Perhaps it's not:  <%
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
 %>

Comment: your button code please

Comment: added an example of a button that I am using

Comment: Offtopic, why would you use in line styling mixed with a class. Better use the css, possibly with a stronger selector if that class is used in other locations that don't need the inning styling. Ontopic, what do you mean with no longer work? The last css is the dominant one so if it is styling related include it before the one of your app (good practice anyway to include libs first). Or is the linking no longer working?

Comment: The buttons no longer are 1) clickable and so therefore 2) don't go to the external links that they originally do. The linking is no longer working.

Comment: I should also mention that this is a .jsp file, not an HTML file.